# Django rest framework APIView patch

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to update `code` field with `patch` method in `APIView`.

I have this so far:

```
class UserDetailView(APIView):

    def patch(self, request, user_id):
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        serializer = UserSerializerRead(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and request will be:

```
[{"action": "replace", "path": "/code", "value": "2"}]
```

i don't understand how patch works, this doesn't change `code`.

Can someone give me some code for this?

Comment: patch is just like put but you don't HAVE to include the entire original object (you could if you'd like). Patch will then run the built in DRF partial_update which basically takes all the keys and sets the specific attribute `model['key']`to equal the new value. You can't naturally update a Multicomponent without some major tinkering.

Comment: Do you have any example for patch? I can't find on net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PATCH` verbs are similar to `POST` or `PUT` except that it'll skip the required fields if they are missing.

Provided the `UserSerializerRead` can update the `User` instance, you request would be:

```
{'code': 2}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use a specific serializer to parse `action` / `path` / `value`